# Exporting with transparent background in premiere

Tags: premiere

I exported a video that starts with fade in and it is transparent so when I put it in another project I won't need to add keyframes every time.

The problem is that the video is "jumping" - watch video here (720p to see better):

I exported with QuickTime format, 32 bit depth and:

- "Animation" video codec, 60 fps, Field order: "Upper First", aspect: square pixels(1.0), quality: 100 and the rest as default.
- "Animation" video codec, 29.976 fps, Field order: "Upper First", aspect: square pixels(1.0), quality: 100 and the rest as default.
- "Animation" video codec, 29.976 fps, Field order: "Progressive", aspect: square pixels(1.0), quality: 100 and the rest as default.
- "**Apple ProRes 4444**" video codec, 60 fps, Field order: "Upper First", aspect: square pixels(1.0), quality: 100 and the rest as default.

I tried all of these export settings and the same problem with everything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to choose "Millions of Colors+" when you select Animation codec, to make sure it generates an alpha channel? Also if it's an animation, you probably want progressive, not interlaced (upper/lower field first = interlaced)

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you are exporting for, whether it be later use in Premiere or transfer to another NLE like Final Cut, you can save your footage as an AAF or XML which will keep all the original timeline information unencoded.  You will still need access to the original footage for this.  This is probably a better solution than exporting with alpha and importing to a separate project.

Comment: As far as alternatives go, using After Effects and importing the After Effects comp as a source would also be a decent option for alternatives, but it still seems like what he is trying to do should work for a fixed leader.

Comment: Well, when all else fails you just have to hack it until it works.

Comment: I used to try that regularly, but I ran out of masking tape to put my video tapes back together... and masking tape doesn't work nearly as well on CF cards.  Couldn't get it to defragment.

Comment: The AAF and XML files aren't working (Like there is no editing), any other suggestions?

Comment: You could try what AJ suggested, I know nothing about After Effects so I can't elaborate on his suggestion.